Angular 17: Error NG0203 When Calling Function with HttpClient Injection from HTML
I'm encountering an issue with Angular 17 where calling a function that has HttpClient injected using the inject function works from the constructor, but throws an error when called from an HTML button click.
Error Message

ERROR Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with runInInjectionContext. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0203
at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:1093:15)
at ɵɵinject (core.mjs:1106:42)
at inject (core.mjs:1192:12)
at _JwtInterceptor.intercept (jwt.interceptor.ts:19:35)
at http.mjs:1722:58
at Object.handle (http.mjs:1723:34)
at fake-backend.ts:68:

**FooterComponent **
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { createdBy, developedByLink } from 'src/app/states/constants';

@Component({
  selector: 'web-studio-footer',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
  styles: [],
})
export class FooterComponent {
  author = createdBy;
  developBy = developedByLink;
  company = ['Home', 'Services', 'Projects', 'Blog'];
  support = ['Help center', 'Terms of service', 'Legal', 'Privacy policy'];
  public message: string | undefined;

  // Use `inject` to obtain the HttpClient
  public http = inject(HttpClient);

  constructor() {
    this.saludar(); // THIS WORKS
  }

  public saludar() {
    console.log('saludar');
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1').subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
        console.log(data);
      },
    });
  }
}


footer.component.html
<button (click)="saludar()" 
        class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill" 
        type="button">
  Contáctenme
</button>

The function works perfectly when called from the constructor, but it fails when triggered by a button click in the HTML.
Question
How can I call the saludar function from the HTML button click without encountering the NG0203 error? Is there a different way to inject the HttpClient or a specific context I should be aware of?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
